# Text box Cursor to the right

Tags: html, css, input, text

I want my cursor to the top right of the text box. I am making a chat application and need cursor to type from top right. What is the HTML/CSS code for that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foRXd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foRXd.png)

Comment: Can you post your code and elaborate on your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take the cursor to the right use `text-align: right` attribute

```css
#FirstName{
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<label for="firstname">Enter Your Name</label>
<input name="firstname" id="FirstName" type="text">
```